# A reviewed post not displayed again in the review queue

Tags: bug, review, review-queue

When I press <kbd>← Back</kbd> in Firefox in the AU review queue, I can usually view the post I’ve just reviewed together with votes of other reviewers. However, sometimes, the post is not shown again.

[image]
This time, it happened on https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/982726. Even reopening the link in another browser tab does not help.

I’ve just encountered this problem the second time already (the first time happened last week IIRC), so I’m asking: What does it mean? Is it a bug, or feature?

Comment: I'm sure that you've encountered this on Low Quality Posts **only**.That's a network wide issue and I have [already reported it on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330577/468333) on July 6.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, I can confirm I’ve experienced this on Low Quality Posts only. Thanks for reporting it on Meta.SE, I hope it will be fixed soon.